# Why is the "more" link at Hacker News randomized?

Tags: sql

It's formatted like this:

http://news.ycombinator.com/x?fnid=r5dSXFDH0o

And if you sit on the page for an hour, the link no longer points anywhere.  How does this work?

Comment: Are you sure this is about SQL?

Answer (score 2):

The navigation section on Hacker News is implemented as continuation, and that argument just identifies it on the server. Once it expires, it loses your connection state. See arclanguage.org for more info.